# Number Format Exception?

Tags: java

```
 if (input.equals("arbitrary"))
    {
        System.out.println("What is your mass?");
        massPerson = Double.parseDouble(input);
        System.out.println("What is the planet's weight?");
        massPlanet = Double.parseDouble(input);
        System.out.println("What is the radius of the planet?");
        radiusPlanet = Double.parseDouble(input);
        weight = arbitraryPlanetWeight(massPerson, massPlanet, radiusPlanet);
    }
```

I'm trying to run a program where it returns your weight on different planets. Everything is working except for my arbitrary planet. if you type `"arbitrary"` in the `void main(string[]args)` it asks `"What is your weight"` and stops running the args. It says i have a `NumberFormatException`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You forgot to read more input. If you are using a Scanner, then after each question you should do e.g. `massPerson = scanner.nextDouble();`

Comment: You aren't actually accepting any input from the user. You just try to parse "arbitrary" over and over as a Double.

Comment: how can i fix that? @tnw

Comment: @Jacob.W How did you read `input` in the first place? Do you have `String input =`something  in your code somewhere? What does it say?

Comment: @thatotherguy Yeah here

Comment: double mass = 0;
        double weight = 0;
        double massPerson = 0;
        double massPlanet = 0;
        double radiusPlanet = 0;
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your mass or \"exit\" to quit:");
        String input = kbReader.nextLine();

Comment: @thatotherguy there you go

Comment: If this is the same method you can then use `massPerson = kbReader.nextDouble();` to read a new double from the user.

Comment: Yay it worked! thank you so much @thatotherguy

Answer (score 0):

I have written you a example of what I assume you are trying to do.
Read all the comments and they should help you understand the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*args is a array of String so for example:
    ["arbitrary"] -> array of length == 1
    or
    ["12.2","11.1","13.3"]
    */

    //If there were no elements in the array this code would break but we will assume there is at least one
    String input = args[0];//put the first element in the array into input

    double weight,massPerson,massPlanet,radiusPlanet;//define variables that we will use

    if (input.equals("arbitrary"))//we look is the string equal to "arbitrary"
    {
        System.out.println("What is your mass?");
        //The next commented out line if it where a command could not pass here because you are trying to interpret "arbitrary" as a double value
        //double massPerson = Double.parseDouble(input);
        //instead you want to user to input the value
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = s.nextLine(); //now input is what the user has entered
        //we assume that what the user has entered is a number
        //if the user input something like "hello" the code would break and you would again get the NumberFormatException
        massPerson = Double.parseDouble(input);
        System.out.println("What is the planet's weight?");
        input = s.nextLine();
        massPlanet = Double.parseDouble(input);
        System.out.println("What is the radius of the planet?");
        input = s.nextLine();
        radiusPlanet = Double.parseDouble(input);
        s.close();//it is important to close the scanner -> there is also a try syntax to do this closing automatically so google : " try-with-resources Statement"
    }
    else{//we have something else as the input
        //lets assume then that the args[] has 3 values which can all be parsed 
        //also since we have the values there is no need to ask the user 
        massPerson = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);//take the first value in the args array and pars it
        massPlanet = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);//take the second value in the args array and pars it
        radiusPlanet = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);//take the third value in the args array and pars it
    }
    //we have all the values at this point so we can calculate the weight
    weight = arbitraryPlanetWeight(massPerson, massPlanet, radiusPlanet);

}

private static double arbitraryPlanetWeight(double massPerson, double massPlanet, double radiusPlanet) {
    System.out.println("Do some calculations");
    return 50;//dummy result
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your String input is equal to arbitrary, It can't be the representation of a number, then the Double.parseDouble(input) launches a parse exception.

You should have variables for each information you want:

```
    if (input.equals("arbitrary"))
    {
        System.out.println("What is your mass?");
        massPerson = Double.parseDouble(massPersonStr);
        System.out.println("What is the planet's weight?");
        massPlanet = Double.parseDouble(massPlanetStr);
        System.out.println("What is the radius of the planet?");
        radiusPlanet = Double.parseDouble(radiusPlanetStr);
        weight = arbitraryPlanetWeight(massPerson, massPlanet, radiusPlanet);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue as that code still doesn't accept input after each question.